# how to overwrite react-select with components prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-select

I'm trying to overwrite the default behaviour of 'noOptionsMessage' (default for noOptionsMessage: noOptionsMessage?: (obj: { inputValue: string }) => string | null;) of react-select using the components prop.

This is what it is stated in the code for react-select:

```
  /*
    This complex object includes all the compositional components that are used
    in `react-select`. If you wish to overwrite a component, pass in an object
    with the appropriate namespace.
  */
  components?: SelectComponentsConfig<OptionType>;
```

This is what I currently have:

```
const components: Props['components'] = {
  LoadingIndicator() {
    return null;
  },
  DropdownIndicator() {
    return null;
  },
  IndicatorSeparator() {
    return null;
  },
  ClearIndicator(props) {
    return (
      <reactSelectComponents.ClearIndicator {...props}>
        <XIcon size="small" />
      </reactSelectComponents.ClearIndicator>
    );
  },
  Input(props) {
    return (
      <reactSelectComponents.Input
        {...props}
        aria-describedby={(props as any).selectProps['aria-describedby']}
      />
    );
  },
  LoadingMessage() {
    return (
      <Flex justify="center" marginY="xlarge">
        <LoadingDots label="Loading options" />
      </Flex>
    );
  },
  ValueContainer(props) {
    return (
      <reactSelectComponents.ValueContainer {...props}>
        <span
          css={{
            alignItems: 'center',
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            width: 40,
          }}
        >
          <SearchIcon color="dim" size="small" />
        </span>
        {props.children}
      </reactSelectComponents.ValueContainer>
    );
  },
};

export function Autocomplete<Option extends BaseOption>(
  props: AutocompleteProps<Option
) {

  return (
    <Select
      components={components}
    />
  );
}
```

I tried moving "const components: Props['components']" inside my Autocomplete component so I have access to the props. But this isn't working as expected. Any thoughts on how I can achieve this??

Comment: I think you're going to have to be clearer about what doesn't appear to be working. You have the right general idea: `components` takes an object of override components. The first thing I tell anyone who is writing an override component is to use the source code of the current component as a template for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Oh yea, thanks for that, looking at the source code would be useful.